# AntD pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

How to change the amount of pagination in Ant Design? Need a maximum of 3 numbers before the dots, and by default 5
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9yvX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `showLessItems` property for antd pagination component.

```
<Pagination total={500} pageSize={10} showLessItems />
```